# Complex sorting in Spring Data JPA Sort object

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-repositories

I want to do this query

```sql
select * from order_config
where group_id like '%PATH%'
order by (group_id = 'PATH') desc
```

and I have this JpaRepository that I want to pass a `Pageable` object with this complex sorting

```kotlin
val sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "group_id")
val pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, sort)

this.findAll(pageable)
```

I have already tried this but it doesn't work

```kotlin
val sort = JpaSort.unsafe(Sort.Direction.DESC, "(group_id = 'PATH')")
val pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, sort)

this.findAll(pageable)
```

How do I build this `Sort` object with this expression instead of a model property?

Comment: Could you share the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use specification API for generating more complex Query. I my code I used this code for creating specification object.

```java
// Instead of Post class pass your own entity class.
public static Specification<Post> search(String keyword) { 
   return ((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
       if (keyword == null) {
           return null;
       }
       return criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("title"), "%" + keyword + "%")); 
   });
}
```

*findAll()* accept specification object too you can pass both specification and pageable object like:

```
this.findAll(search("PATH"), pageable);
```