# Specify complex sorting criteria when requesting Spring Data JPA repository

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories, jpa-criteria, pageable

I'm requesting paged and sorted data from my database, specified via `Pageable` with following repository API:

```java
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor.findAll(Specification<MyEntity> filter, Pageable pageable)
```

`Pageable` contains a `Sort` with simple sorting criteria, such as **sort column X in descending order**.

Sometimes, `Sort` contains one column which actually doesn't exist in the underlying table, which must be replaced by a complex conditional `ORDER BY` expression:

```sql
ORDER BY CASE WHEN entity_to='CUSTOMER' THEN entity_to_id ELSE (CASE WHEN entity_from='CUSTOMER' THEN entity_from_id END) END
```

Indeed, I can rebuild the `Sort` instance in `Pageable` so that this non-existing column gets removed, but I didn't find a way to inject the complex `ORDER BY` expression in that case.

I tried to find a way, to enrich the resulting query from this invocation of the Repository. I hoped that I can do it by adding another `Specification` filter, but I got an error (`No explicit selection and an implicit one could not be determined`), and I'm not sure that the order-by will be applied to the final query built by the Repository implementation:

```java
...
filter = filter.and(
        (root, query, cb) -> {
            final var customerLiteral = cb.literal("CUSTOMER");
            final var caseExpression = cb.selectCase(root.get(MyEntity_.ENTITY_TO))
                    .when(customerLiteral, root.get(MyEntity_.ENTITY_TO_ID)).otherwise(
                            cb.selectCase(root.get(MyEntity_.ENTITY_FROM))
                                    .when(customerLiteral, root.get(MyEntity_.ENTITY_FROM_ID)).otherwise(0));
            final var order = ascElseDesc ? cb.asc(caseExpression) : cb.desc(caseExpression);

            final var cq = cb.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
            return cb.exists(cq.select(root).orderBy(order).subquery(MyEntity.class));
        }
);

repository.findAll(filter, pageable);
```

I don't want to drop the current implementation which leverages Spring Data's `findAll(filter, pageable)`. I only would like to **enrich** it in one case. How can it be done?

Comment: Similar, but didn't solve my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66361771/complex-sorting-in-spring-data-jpa-sort-object

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34722669/complex-sort-with-spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that case you can create `@Formula` column in `MyEntity` with custom SQL and then refer it in `Pageable` as regular entity field